# Xcode errors when uploading iOS 7 app via Organizer, every time

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

Xcode is giving me 3 errors whenever I try to submit my iOS7 app through Xcode. The errors are:

1. Apple's web service operation was not successful
2. Unable to authenticate package
3. The bundle 'com.x.x' at bundle path 'Payload/x.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate. at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

Comment: Did you sign the release build with a distribution (not a development) certificate?

Comment: I am having a same issue. I submitted app to store many times so I am quite sure that all configurations are correct :(

Comment: Did you find any solution to fix this?

Comment: I found a solution. I changed my application to run on the new iOS7 architectures and submitted it to iTunesConnect without a problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem too. What do you mean to run on the new iOS 7 architecture??

Comment: Select your target and change from the old iOS6 armv6, armv7 to iOS7 armv6, armv7, 64 bit, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "**Valid Architectures**" in Build Settings to "**$(ARCHS_STANDARD)**". After banging my head on this for almost 2 days, and thinking I had tried the architectures fix, I realized that I had only tried changing the "Architectures" to standard (which kept giving me an error on build), and not the "Valid Architectures".

Comment: worked for me too thanks for sharing :), you saved alot of my time.