# unable to authenticate the package, not signed using the apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to upload build for existing live app update for iOS7 and getting the below error in picture.

1. I am using correct distribution profile with same bundle identifier.
2. using standard architecture and deployment target 4.3
3. i have declared all the icons in .plist file.

I am sending .ipa file to client to upload using **application loader 2.9** 
he doesn't want to share his iTunes account credentials 
so I am archiving project then select **adhoc enterprise** distribution option from Xcode  then select the app store distribution profile from drop down then export it and send it to the client.

could anyone please help me out . I am trying to solve this error since last 48 hours.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to send an .ipa to a client or upload it to the app store ? Because adhoc enterprise distribution and app store distribution aren't the same.

Comment: Actually I am sending the .ipa to client then he will upload the .ipa for apple store. this ipa is signed with app store distribution certificate.

Comment: Have you tried giving them the .xcarchive generated at the end of your archive process ? Then they can validate it through the App Store themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is quite clear - the certificate you used for signing is **NOT** an app store certificate. As you don't have access to the client's iTunes account, I assume you got the certificate from your client as well - probably he gave you a wrong one, e.g. a development certificate or an ad hoc certificate, or the certificate is not valid anymore.

Ask your client for a new certificate, stating exactly what you need (sometimes they are not that knowledgable about app distribution:-).

**UPDATE**

Maybe this helps in your case - apparently there are some other issues with submitting:

[Xcode errors when uploading iOS 7 app via Organizer, every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938216/xcode-errors-when-uploading-ios-7-app-via-organizer-every-time)

Comment: actually I am unable to login developer.apple.com client member center and downloaded the app store distributor provisioning profile but I can't login to itunesconnect using that credentials .
has many vendors so don't want to share it.

is there any way to send build to the client so he can upload himself to apple store without sending the project code in Xcode 5.

Comment: Do you have the certificate installed (the infamous p12 file) on you computer? Otherwise your app store profile won't be valid.

Comment: I just see that you are deploying to 4.3 - do you really have to support that iOS version? That might give some issues too.

Comment: Now he agree to share credential now I am getting " unable to process info.plist validation at this time , due to general error please try again when i validate archive in Xcode 5

Comment: This one might help you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353049/unable-to-process-application-info-plist-validation-at-this-time-due-to-a-genera